# Can I deal just one card at a time in Klondike?

Tags: solitaire, computers, klondike-solitaire

I installed Microsoft's Solitaire Collection, but in Klondike I cannot set any option to deal only one card in every 'turn'.

Is it possible somehow?

**Update**: Ian Hutchinson pointed to an important thing: in the game there is two different "Settings" menu. One is available from the front page, after you logged in (automatically) and game chooser menu is displayed. The second one is available **only after you already started a game** (Klondike in this case). So, if you want change, it will generate a loss in the statistics if you do not finish a 3-card game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press F5 or go to the upper right corner and click Options (the gear) while you are in a Klondike game. The draw and scoring options are under Game Settings, which will either be an option to click or be the option that comes up.

Answer (score 1):

No. Klondike solitaire traditonally requires that you deal yourself three cards, and can only play the "top" card from that deal. Once you play the top card, the card below becomes available. If Microsoft removed the three card restriction,there wouldn't be much of a game left. At that point, the game would devolve into discovering if a required card was buried in one of the stacks.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. It seems that single card Klondike is a [standard variation](http://www.solitairecity.com/Help/Klondike_Rules.shtml). It also looks to me like "Klondike" and "Klondike by threes" are both part of the [Microsoft Solitaire collection](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-in/app/klondike-solitaire-collection/a03e4b4a-15e7-4274-ac40-24ecf2aed289#).

Comment: @ire_and_curses, your link to [Microsoft Solitaire Collection](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/microsoft-solitaire-collection/1a36fd17-5161-4651-ae2d-13384e427ea8) is actually to, TreeCardGames [Klondike Solitaire Collection](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-in/app/klondike-solitaire-collection/a03e4b4a-15e7-4274-ac40-24ecf2aed289). Microsoft's collection has "classic Klondike", and TreeCardGames has several different variants of Klondike, including the American variant using single card deals. I dont believe Microsoft has single card, but if it does it is in the Settings Menu.

Comment: @user1873 I didn't find way to change it in settings menu, that's my base problem... even if some strings on the UI suggest there is a way to change...

Comment: @ire_and_curses thanks for the... errm... "mistake" :-) I think that Klondike what you linked will solve my base problem - however I keep this question open, because I want to know if there is a way to change that setting somehow. Until now Microsoft always provided both one- and three-card solitaire in its solitaire applications (from Windows 3.0 to Windows 7), so I wondering why this approach changed now. As I know in Hungary the one-card solitaire is the most known version of this game.